# How to annotate that a function returns a union of input types?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a function that can take a list of classes as an input argument, and will return an instance of one of these input classes, depending on other arguments. How can I annotate the function so that `mypy` will understand this?

I've tried using [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type), which works well in the single argument case, but I don't know how to generalise it to a list of types.

Here is a minimal example of what I am looking for.

```py
def single_foo(type: Type[T]) -> T: ...

bar = single_foo(int)
reveal_type(bar)  # int


def multi_foo(types: X) -> Y: ... 

bar = multi_foo([str, int, ...])
reveal_type(bar)  # should be Union[str, int, ...]
```

Comment: Are you returning a class or an instance of that class?

Comment: I am returning an instance of one of the passed classes. E.g, `bar` could be `"abc"` or `1`, in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Union`:

```
from typing import List, Type, Union

def multi_foo(t: List[Union[Type[int], Type[str]][) -> List[Union[int, str]]:
    ...
```

Comment: I think that only works for `str` and `int`, not a dynamic list of arbitrary types.